# Vetor que gere elementos

Tags: c, array

Gostaria de gerar um vetor onde seu elemento da posição seguinte seja acrescido de 1. Por exemplo: seja um `vetor[3]`, gostaria que `v[0] = 1` e `v[1] = v[0] + 1`, `v[2] = v[1] + 1` e assim por diante. Como faria isso?

Segue meu código por enquanto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int N, M, i;

    int *v;

    printf ("Entre com N: ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);
    printf ("Entre com M: ");
    scanf ("%d", &M);

    v = (int *)malloc(M * sizeof (int));

    v[0] = 1;

    for (i=0; i < M; ++i){
        v[i]++;                
        printf ("%d ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O principal problema do código é que ele não está atribuindo nada para o vetor. Retirei o que não estava sendo usado, organizei e modernizei o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int M;
    printf("Entre com M: ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    int *v = malloc(M * sizeof (int));
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
        v[i] = i + 1;                
        printf ("%d ", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/i8qZRz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pwjtodad-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Malloc.c).

Answer (score 2):

O erro no seu código está aqui:

```
for (i=0; i < M; ++i){
    v[i]++;  // Essa linha não faz a soma que você quer          
    printf ("%d ", v[i]);
}
```

O correto é você usar: `v[i] = v[i] + 1;`.

Caso você queira que o usuário entre com os valores do vetor, você pode fazer desse jeito:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int N, M, i;
    int *v;

    printf ("Entre com N: ");
    scanf ("%d", &N);

    v = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof (int));

    printf ("Entre com os valores do vetor (M): ");
    for(i=0; i<N;i++){
        scanf ("%d \n", &M);
        v[i] = M;
    }

    for (i=0; i < N; ++i){
        v[i] = v[i] + 1;                
        printf ("Vetor[%d]=%d ",i, v[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IjBola).